# Read richtextBox line by line in order to run oracle Command?

Tags: c#

I have a Rich Text Box that holds multiple insert statement and what I want to do is run all insert statement that inside my richtextbox. But having below error.

**Message=ORA-00911: invalid character**
*When I open the Text visualizer to look richTextBox.Text expression My value is inside the  richTextBox.Text like below:*

```
INSERT INTO TBLMESS (ID, TEXT) VALUES ('1','hello');
INSERT INTO TBLMESS (ID, TEXT) VALUES ('2','hello');
INSERT INTO TBLMESS (ID, TEXT) VALUES ('3','hello');
INSERT INTO TBLMESS (ID, TEXT) VALUES ('4','hello');
INSERT INTO TBLMESS (ID, TEXT) VALUES ('5','hello');
INSERT INTO TBLMESS (ID, TEXT) VALUES ('6','hello');
```

**Code:**

```
   conn1.Open();
   OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(richTextBoxScript.Text, conn1);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi i tried your answer but still same problem. If I run the insert statements directly inside golden application it works.

Comment: could you please post  the error message?

Comment: did you check the `Problem 2` part in my answer?

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi your problem 2 part is not a problem for me to run the insert statement with ID type as string

Comment: This title is somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 0):

So how do we run multiple statements in a single command? Well, a reasonable first guess may be to add multiple statements directly to our SQL string and separate them with the typical “;” separator:

```
var sql = @"INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE( NKEY, STEXT ) VALUES( 123, 'HELLO WORLD' );
              INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE( NKEY, STEXT ) VALUES( 456, 'HELLO AGAIN' );";
```

Unfortunately, this won’t work with Oracle; try it and you’ll get an error that looks something like:

**Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00911: invalid character.**

Informative, isn’t it? Fortunately, the solution is quite simple: surround the statements in an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
 var sql = @"BEGIN
            INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE( NKEY, STEXT ) VALUES( 123, 'HELLO WORLD' );
            INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE( NKEY, STEXT ) VALUES( 456, 'HELLO AGAIN' );
            END;";
```

Can it really be that simple? Well, yes